# CompositeView - An event which will be fired post rendering of all the child records

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, composite-view

I'm trying to render list of records using CompositeView and I'm unable to identify an event which will be fired post rendering of all the child records.

I went through the documentation and found below methods which have not worked yet -

1. onRenderCollection - after the collection of models has been rendered
2. onRender - after everything has been rendered
3. render:collection - *tried it just for the heck of it*

Below is the current code snippet -

```
        View.childItem = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: childTpl,
            tagName: 'tr'
        });


        View.parentPane = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
            template: parentTpl,
            childView: View.childItem,
            childViewContainer: "#childList",
            events: {

            },
            onAfterRender: function (ev) {
                $('tbody').css('height', '210px')); // trying to control the height dynamically..
            },

        });
```

Comment: `childView: View.childTpl` should that not be `childView: View.childItem`

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [onRender](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.compositeview.html#events-and-callbacks):

> Additionally, after the composite view has been rendered, an `onRender`
>   method will be called. You can implement this in your view to provide
>   custom code for dealing with the view's el after it has been rendered.

```
View.parentPane = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: parentTpl,
  childView: View.childTpl,
  childViewContainer: "#childList",
  onRender: function () {
    $('tbody').css('height', '210px')); // trying to control the height dynamically..
  }
});
```

Comment: strangely my onRender was firing at the start of the render event and not after it and hence was hoping for a onAfterRender which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `render:collection`/`onRenderCollection`.  See ["render" event](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.collectionview.html#render-event) in the Marionette documentation.